# Can I forbid temporary objects as parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, move-semantics, pass-by-rvalue-reference

Let's say I have the function:

```
void foo(Object& o) {
    /* only query o, dont alter it*/
}
```

Is it possible to call this function only with already constructed objects and have Visual Studio throw a compile error if I call the function with a temporary object?

```
struct Object {
    /*Members*/
}

void foo(Object& o) {
    /* only query o, dont alter it*/
}

int main() {
    Object o = Object();
    foo(o); // allow this
    foo(Object()) // but disallow this
}
```

Comment: That's the default for non-constant references, it's not possible to have a non-constant reference to a temporary (or rvalue) object. Except for the Visual Studio C++ compiler, which adds a non-portable extension that allows it (it can be turned off IIRC).

Comment: That's already what happens?

Comment: btw `Object o = Object();` is `Object o;`

Comment: I am indeed using MSVC, and it does not complain about the temporary object. GCC however does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your parameter is not `const`, the function won't accept temporaries.

If your parameter is `const`, the function accepts both temporary and regular objects.

But if you want to prevent that, you can use the following

```
struct Object{};
void foo(const Object& o) {
    /*only query o, don't alter it*/
}
void foo(Object&& ) = delete;

int main() {
    Object o;
    foo(o); // allow this
    foo(Object{}); // but disallow this
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/8Mdv4T)

Comment: thank you very much!
I am using MSVC and the compiler does not complain about the temporary object in my case. GCC however does!

Comment: @Raildex  msvc doesn't compile it too. See https://godbolt.org/z/9cYse7

Comment: I was talking about my case in the question :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Explicitly deleting the `const &&` overload

A temporary object can have its lifetime extended by binding it to a `const` lvalue reference (in a function call), whereas it cannot bind to a non-`const` lvalue reference. This means that your original example implements the sought after behaviour (*cannot be invoked with temporary objects*), but at the cost of making the parameter non-`const` (even though the implementation only queries and does not mutate the object). This arguably violates `const` correctness.

As your free function API is inspecting an `Object` object, you could consider changing it into a member function and use ref-qualifiers to explicitly delete the overload that will be chosen by overload resolution for temporary objects. A first approach could be to simply delete the `&&` overload:

```
struct Object {
    // ...
    
    void foo() const & {}
    void foo()       && = delete;
};

int main() {
    Object o = Object();
    const Object co = Object();

    o.foo();
    co.foo();
    
    //Object().foo();  // error: use of deleted function
}
```

However, this does not prohibit the, albeit somewhat contrived, case of *const temporary objects* as well as *movable from const objects* (const xvalues), as the deleted non-`const` rvalue ref-qualifier overload is not viable for a `const` rvalue argument:

```
std::move(co).foo();  // Accepted.
static_cast<const Object&&>(Object()).foo();  // Accepted.
```

Thus, instead of explicitly deleting the `&&` overload, we can remove also the corner case by instead explicitly deleting the `const &&` overload, as this will also be the overload of choice for non-`const` temporary objects:

```
struct Object {
    // ...
    
    void foo() const & {}
    void foo() const && = delete;
};

int main() {
    Object o = Object();
    const Object co = Object();

    o.foo();
    co.foo();
    
    //std::move(o).foo();   // error: use of deleted function
    //std::move(co).foo();  // error: use of deleted function

    //Object().foo();  // error: use of deleted function
    //static_cast<const volatile Object&&>(Object()).foo();  // error: use of deleted function
}
```

We may note that the same approach is used e.g. for the `std::ref` and `std::cref` helper functions of `std::reference_wrapper`; from [[functional.sym]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/functional.syn):

> ```
> // [refwrap], reference_­wrapper
> // ...
> template <class T> void ref(const T&&) = delete;
> template <class T> void cref(const T&&) = delete;
>
> // ...
> ```

as you naturally want to delete a reference wrapper for temporary objects.